# query a file based on an input in bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I would like to query a huge zipped genomic file (dbsnp.gz) with the following columns formatted as follows:

```
chr1    196575462   rs115411599 A   G   .   .   RS=115411599;RSPOS=196575462;dbSNPBuildID=132;SSR=0;SAO=0;VP=0x050000080005040436000100;GENEINFO=KCNT2:343450;WGT=1;VC=SNV;INT;ASP;VLD;HD;KGPhase1;KGPhase3;CAF=0.9994,0.000599;COMMON=1
```

I would like to extract columns 4 and 5 by querying the first two columns, or the third (or all three IF IT MAKES IT ANY FASTER). column 1+2 or column 3 are enough to distinguish these entries.

my input file (file.txt) has 50+ entires as such:

```
chr1:196575462   rs115411599
```

I initially thought of using awk and zgrep

```
for i in $(awk -F'\t' '{print $1}' file.txt); do

'{$i == $(zcat dbsnp.gz | awk -F'\t' {print $1,$2} OFS=":"})' '{print $0}'

done
```

This does not work? Should I stick with awk? or use zgrep?

Comment: You can't mix shell and awk like you're trying to. What's the exact criterion and the desired output?

Comment: I would like to pull records from dbsnp.gz where $1 ':' $2  matches $1 from file.txt

Comment: Do you want to `zgrep "^chr1" dbsnp.gz` ?

Comment: zgrep takes so long. Wanted to compare that with awk!

Comment: and running `zcat` (or `zgrep`) inside a `while` loop means repeated scans of the `huge zipped genomic file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated w/ tips from Ed Morton - thanks]

Assumptions:

- the combination of columns 1+2 are unique within `file.txt`
- column 3 is unique within `file.txt`

Start with some sample data files:

```
$ cat gene.dat
chr1    196575462   rs115411599 A   G   .   .   RS=115411599;RSPOS=196575462;dbSNPBuildID=132;SSR=0;SAO=0;VP=0x050000080005040436000100;GENEINFO=KCNT2:343450;WGT=1;VC=SNV;INT;ASP;VLD;HD;KGPhase1;KGPhase3;CAF=0.9994,0.000599;COMMON=1
chr2    196575462   rs115411588 A   G   .   .   RS=115411599;RSPOS=196575462;dbSNPBuildID=132;SSR=0;SAO=0;VP=0x050000080005040436000100;GENEINFO=KCNT2:343450;WGT=1;VC=SNV;INT;ASP;VLD;HD;KGPhase1;KGPhase3;CAF=0.9994,0.000599;COMMON=1
chr3    196575462   rs115411577 A   G   .   .   RS=115411599;RSPOS=196575462;dbSNPBuildID=132;SSR=0;SAO=0;VP=0x050000080005040436000100;GENEINFO=KCNT2:343450;WGT=1;VC=SNV;INT;ASP;VLD;HD;KGPhase1;KGPhase3;CAF=0.9994,0.000599;COMMON=1

# go ahead and create a *gz file we can use with zcat:

$ gzip -c gene.dat > gene.dat.gz

$ cat file.txt
chr1:196575462   rs115411599
chr2:196500077   rs115400077
chr3:196500088   rs115400088
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
# for first file, use fields 1+2 and 3 as indexes for our associative arrays

FNR==NR { match1[$1,$2] ; match2[$3] ; next }

# for second file, if fields 1+2 matches an index in the match1[] array then print fields $4/$5; if we found a match then go to next line in file

( ($1,$2) in match1 ) { print $4,$5 ; next }

# for second file, if field 3 matches an index in the match2[] array then print fields $4/$5

(      $3 in match2 ) { print $4,$5 }

  # for our first file we will replace : with <space> ; this gives us 3 fields from first file
  # for our second file we will feed the results of the zcat operation
' <(sed 's/:/ /g' file.txt) <(zcat gene.dat.gz)
```

And the output from running the above:

```
A G
```

A **big benefit** of this approach is that we scan each file just **ONCE** (eg, the sample code in the question shows `zcat dbsnp.gz` being run/scanned repeatedly inside a `while` loop).

Comment: I assume FNR was made for this reason. It is way faster than looping! Thanks

Comment: `awk` has access to each (input) file name (something like `/dev/fd###` for the redirections in the example) via the `FILENAME` variable so it would be possible to test `FILENAME` for each record read and then determine if this is the first, second, third ... nth file; but, yeah, `FNR==NR` certainly makes the coding a bit easier when you want to distinguish between 2x files

Comment: Use of `match2[$3]` in the comparison is going to make `match2[]` end up far larger than if you used `$3 in match2`, i.e. the size of all unique values across both input files instead of just the list present in `file.txt`. Ditto for `match1[]`. When you change to use `in` for the comparison you also no longer need to assign the array entries to `=1` in the FNR==NR block.

Comment: @EdMorton wasn't quite following your comment; found [this item](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html#Reference-to-Elements) ... so just *testing* for an array entry creates an array entry, right?  I've updated the answer with what I think you were suggesting ... I know the parens aren't needed but (for me) they provide a bit more clarity

Comment: Testing that an array entry is populated creates an array entry. Testing that an array index is present does not. So `if (foo[7])` will create `foo[7]` if it didn't already exist (populated with zero-or-null like an unset scalar variable) while `if (7 in foo)` will not create `foo[7]`. You might want to change `$1"."$2 in match1` to `($1"."$2) in match1` as idk if the string concatenation takes higher precedence than the `in` test and adding the parens makes the code clearer anyway.

Comment: Finally - consider using `match1[$1,$2]` and `($1,$2) in match1` instead of using concatenation with a `.` since that's what the `,` (`SUBSEP`) exists to do.